# Drupal Form-API: #field_prefix doesn't work on textfield

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-fapi

I'm trying to implement #field_prefix on a text field so I can add some extra UI to my form.

I have a module where I'm doing other overrides like this, with a function that basically looks like this:

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
    if ($form_id == "contenttype_node_form"){
        $form['field_contenttype_fieldname'][0]['#prefix'] = 'prefix';  //this line works           
        $form['field_contenttype_fieldname'][0]['#field_prefix'] = 'field_prefix';  //this line doesn't work
    }
```

Here's the docs, seems pretty straight forward:
http://api.drupal.org/api/file/developer/topics/forms_api_reference.html/6#field_prefix

I've renamed my theme to effectively disable it - should prove I don't have any other overrides hanging around that would conflict.

What am I missing?

**Update:**
Ended up overriding theme_form_element to insert my prefix manually when the #field_name meets the right condition.  Feels hacky, but text_textfield simply doesn't support #field_prefix.

Comment: None of that should work, as it should be `modulename_form_alter` instead of `modulename_formalter`...

Comment: my mistake in typing it in.  the prefix line works as expected.

Comment: OK, just checking. It happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that as a CCK field `field_contenttype_fieldname` isn't actually a textfield, but a custom FormAPI field CCK provides that's *like* a textfield, and as such it doesn't consume the `field_prefix` attribute.

Try `print_r()`ing that field out of the `$form` and see what its `#type` is.

Comment: yep, that's exactly it.  it's a 'text_textfield'.  i can override #type and force it to a 'textfield' and my #field_prefix now works.  any dangers in doing this?  how is 'text_textfield' any different?

Comment: It may interfere with CCK's multiple-value handling, but otherwise if it works it works.